# Cordova - how to check whether geolocation permition was granted

Tags: cordova, permissions, geolocation

Due to the new privacy policy, I need to find out if the user has allowed permission to gelocation before the system dialog is displayed. Is there a way to get this information in Cordova application? I tried this:

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'geolocation' }).then( .... );
```

but it looks like navigator.permission hasn`t been implemented in Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [cordova-plugin-permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-permission) that should do just what you need. Otherwise you can rely on `PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED` from [cordova-plugin-geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#constants) since requesting the position the first time will trigger the permission request box.

Lastly you can use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) see https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#permissionstatus-constants

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only for Android

Comment: Answer edited...

Comment: Added diagnostics plugin